# use "valueForKey:" to access private variable but got run-time error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a `MyService` class, I made it a **singleton** like this:

header :

```
@interface MyService : NSObject
+(MyService *)sharedInstance;
@end
```

implementation:

```
@implementation MyService {
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
}

+ (VADispatchQueue *)sharedInstance {
    static MyService *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyService  alloc] init];
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("my.custom.queue", NULL);
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

...
@end
```

As you see above, I defined a **private** variable `dispatch_queue_t queue` in `MyService` class.

In another class, I try to access this private variable by:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = [[MyService sharedInstance] valueForKey:@"queue"];
```

But above code causes **run-time error**:

```
caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[<MyService 0x7a068440> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key queue."
```

Why I get this error? (I have another place use the same way to access a BOOL private variable of another class and it works fine there)

Comment: if you change this variable for a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained you yesterday (today?) key-value coding forms accessor selectors from keys. You do not have accessor methods to be executed o the selector. (For the protocol: It can access ivars directly, see `+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly`, but you do not want to do that.)

Make it a property. This will automatically add accessors. Or implement accessors manually.

Comment: which means I need to expose this variable though I'd prefer to make it private? And if make it a property, it is public, then, there is no point for me to access it with key-value coding way... Do you have a solution about accessing private variable?

Comment: Well, making something private and then accessing it from outside seems to be a misconception. However, you do not have to do this. You can implement the accessor methods privately or you can have a private property in a class continuation. There is no need for publicity. This is a concept of compile time, kvc works on runtime.

Comment: I just need to access it in my unit test case, that's why I prefer to keep it private, there is no point to expose it just for test case. I think I will post another question for this scenario.

Comment: If you ask such a Q, the A ist quite clear: Unit tests should test the outside behavior, not the implementation. Testing by assuming an implementation will break our test on refactoring – one of the most important cases for unit tests. Do not do this.

Comment: Well, then I will ask a very general question in iOS: how to access private variable. I am curious about this topic anyway. For this current question, I can accept your answer.

Comment: Accessing a private variable, a private method, a private $whatever is something you should not do in a unit test. A successful unit test should work after a complete redesign of a tested unit into a new working unit without relying on internals.

Comment: As I said, forget about unit test. I am saying that I am curious about how to access private variable in ios/objective-c in general. That's the topic I want to understand.

Comment: A private variable is *private*. A third party is not supposed to be able to access it.

Comment: It is the meaning of private that it is not accessible.

Comment: "is not supposed to be" is not equal not-doable. Even it is a unrecommended way, I would like to know any possibility of accessing private variable. Like in Java, we can use java-reflection to access private field, though it is private & is not supposed to be accessible.

Comment: There is a way to access private variables in objective-c through runtime calls, but you'll have to ask it as a separate question, since the answer would be outside the scope of the original question above (which is why an error is occurring).

Comment: You can read the ivars using the runtime environment. And as mentioned in my answer, the class can say that it allows access to its ivars via kvc.

Comment: @KevinLow, that's exactly what I said in my previous comment, I am going to ask it anyway in another post. I just want to let Amin Negm-Awad understand my point, though I understand it is not recommended to access private variable in general.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because it's ivar variable and KVC working with properties. So you need to create property instead ivar variable.

Comment: KVC works with accessor methods. Properties usually create accessor methods automatically.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It won't create accessors if it's @dynamic marked property ;)

Comment: No, this is not the point. You can write the accessors manually. KVC is very much older (a decade?) than `@property`. Therefore declared properties are not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I know that. It will automatically just call methods

Comment: What is it for this explanation?) Are you trying to teach me?)

Comment: You said to him – and to anybody else reading this Q and A, when having the same or a similar problem –, that he needs a property, because it works on it. This is wrong. You do not need a property. Even in many situation properties seem to be the easiest und likely best way to implement accessors, there might be reason not to do so. In such a case your answer is misleading. It should be no big deal to clarify that in your answer.

Comment: Yes, but from his post you can see, that he wan't to save value as well, and having just accessors is not the best way. That's why I suppose using properties and tried to explain it in the easiest way. 
Sure it's not the full truth and I could write full article how it works or etc. .. But questing was how to fix this issue=)  And we should try to explain it as easy as it can be to fix such problem (and it this case it will solve 95% of possible situations). As well still it not means that I do not understand how it works deeply inside. Hope you understand my point of view =)

Comment: Hey, what are you guys arguing about? Don't both of you suggest me to create a property? I don't understand what is the difference between your answers & you are arguing?

Comment: There is difference. He wrote you source of problem solving and explain more deeply how it works. I wrote you result(properties) that we have from that source, that all world using now, but I didn't explain why it will help you.